# Cut a Grouped Circle in Half without Extra Borders Being Created

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created this intricate circle object that is made up of a group of objects.

[image]

I want to simply cut the circle and half but can't seem to get what I want.

When I use the knife tool, it kind of works but it adds extra strokes to it and I don't want.

[image]

Then tried using the pathfinder tool (minus) and I'm just  I just left with the outside half- moon circle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't modify the object, create a [**Clipping Mask**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html) instead.

[image: Illustrator clipping mask example]

1. Draw a shape covering areas of the object you want to show
2. Select the new shape and the intricate circle objects
3. <kbd>Object > Clipping Mask > Make</kbd>